# Postgres- hard delete with cascade to relation table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete, cascading-deletes

I am writing sql query (using **postgres 14**) to `DELETE` row from `tags` table:

**Tags** table:

| id | team_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 91 | Dev Team |

But, It should `CASCADE` to the **team_member_tag** table too:

| id | team_member_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 289 | 1 |

Joined by **team_member** table:

| id | team_id | member_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 289 | 91 | 1 |

I tested it, but It seems like my `INNER JOIN` is out of order. I do not know what I am doing wrong?

My query:

```
            DELETE tag t, team_member_tag tmt
            FROM tag
            LEFT JOIN team_member_tag tmt ON t.id = tmt.team_member_id
            LEFT JOIN team_member tm ON tm.id = tmt.team_member_id 
            WHERE team_member.member_id = :teamId
            AND team_member.member_id = :teamMemberId

    $stmt->bindValue("teamId", 91 PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue("teamMemberId", 289, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

I tried first with `SELECT`, and it says query is **OK** but returns nothing:

```
SELECT
    name
FROM tag as t
LEFT JOIN team_member_tag tmt ON t.id = tmt.team_member_id
LEFT JOIN team_member tm ON tm.id = tmt.team_member_id
WHERE name = 'Dev Team'
AND tmt.team_member_id = 289 AND tm.team_id = 91;
```

Comment: tag_id should only be in one table and not in two of them

Comment: tag id is in one place? @nbk

Comment: i meant team_id is in tag and team_member  so the structure makes not much sense

Comment: Recreated, still does not work.. @nbk

Comment: I updated my post with edits I made. Can you please take a look? Thanks @nbk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For postgres, you need a CTE to do that, if you don't have casacding references
see

```
    SELECT t.*, tmt.*
    FROM tag t
    INNER JOIN team_member_tag tmt ON t.id = tmt.tag_id
    INNER JOIN team_member ON tmt.team_member_id = team_member.id
    INNER JOIN member ON team_member.member_id = member.id
    WHERE team_member.team_id = 91
    AND team_member.member_id = 1;
```

| id | team_id | name | id | team_member_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 91 | Dev Team | 1 | 289 | 1 |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

```
WITH Bdeletes AS (
    DELETE FROM team_member_tag tmt 
  WHERE tmt.team_member_id IN (SELECT team_member.id
  FROM team_member
  WHERE team_member.team_id = 91
    AND team_member.member_id = 1) 
  returning tmt.tag_id 
)
DELETE from tag t
  where t.id
  IN( SELECT Tag_id FROM Bdeletes)
```

> ```
> DELETE 1
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM tag
```

| id | team_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM team_member_tag
```

| id | team_member_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xHlFm9nN)

But if you add a REFERENCE you can do it in one adding more refences would also delete more rows from other tables

```
CREATE TABLE Tag 
    ("id" int  primary key, "team_id" int, "name" varchar(8))
;
    
INSERT INTO Tag 
    ("id", "team_id", "name")
VALUES
    (1, 91, 'Dev Team')
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 1
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE team_member_tag 
    ("id" int, "team_member_id" int, "tag_id" int references Tag (id) on delete cascade )
;
    
INSERT INTO team_member_tag 
    ("id", "team_member_id", "tag_id")
VALUES
    (1, 289, 1)
;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 1
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE team_member 
    ("id" int, "team_id" int, "member_id" int)
;
    
INSERT INTO team_member 
    ("id", "team_id", "member_id")
VALUES
    (289, 91, 1)
;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 1
> ```

```
CREATE TABLe member("id" int)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
INSERT INTO member VALUES(1)
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 1
> ```

```
    SELECT t.*, tmt.*
    FROM tag t
    INNER JOIN team_member_tag tmt ON t.id = tmt.tag_id
    INNER JOIN team_member ON tmt.team_member_id = team_member.id
    INNER JOIN member ON team_member.member_id = member.id
    WHERE team_member.team_id = 91
    AND team_member.member_id = 1;
```

| id | team_id | name | id | team_member_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 91 | Dev Team | 1 | 289 | 1 |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

```
    DELETE FROM tag
  WHERE id IN
      (SELECT tag_id FROM  team_member_tag tmt 
  INNER JOIN team_member ON tmt.team_member_id = team_member.id
  WHERE team_member.team_id = 91
    AND team_member.member_id = 1)
```

> ```
> DELETE 1
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM tag
```

| id | team_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM team_member_tag
```

| id | team_member_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8z3P0xX7)

Comment: Thank you so much! The second example did it for me! This is gold @nbk